# Selecting observation in SAS then do

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to do if this column = 'Johanna' then the value in column salary should be divided by 100 in SAS.

What is the best approach to do that in SAS

Thank you

Mr.F

Comment: FYI here is the guide on how to ask your questions on SO and get quick responses. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL `update` can modify a value in a table with out rebuilding (rewriting) the entire table.  A DATA Step will rewrite an output data set.

```
Proc SQL;
  * divide a persons salary by a constant;
  update mytable
  set salary = salary / 100
  where name = 'Joanna'
  ;
```

Repeated submits of the code will divide the salary each time, so be aware of that.

```
  update mytable
  set salary = salary / (select salary from mytable where name = 'OtherValue')
  where name = 'Joanna'
  ;
```

The selection criteria for the denominator (`where name = 'OtherValue'`) can be any valid selection for the table that returns a single row.

If you want to divide a value by a value in a next or prior row make a new question and provide some context and sample data.

Comment: Thank you Richard. you comments helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re using a data step

```
If columnName = 'Joanna' then salary = salary/100;
```

Comment: Thank you for you help
Do you know how can I use this same value that  have on salary and divided by another value on the salary column?

Comment: Edit your existing question to add new relevant information.  Create a new question for a new question.  A question gives you lots of space to explain the situation and what is not working for you.